# What optics and display are used in Microsoft HoloLens?

Tags: design, optics, computer-engineering

How does Microsoft project an image so close to the eye yet understandable by the brain?

How is the display transparent?

This link has good information but is speculative.
https://www.reddit.com/r/HoloLens/comments/2v0nac/hololens_display_tech_and_what_to_expect_from_it/

What materials are used?

For a list of patents see this: http://vrwiki.wikispaces.com/Microsoft+HoloLens

Comment: @Air I wasn't sure if I missed an article posted by Microsoft. Also Microsoft has posted many Patents about it, so if someone had gone through all of them it is even more probable someone could answer my question. I am reading through them, but I'm not sure. I don't understand why it is a bad thing to ask, even if no one can answer bc at least now there is a possibility of an answer.